# Angels Frequently Visiting Avraham

Tags: malach-angel, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha, hagar

Rashi ([Bereishis 16:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.16.13?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.16.13.2&lang2=bi)) notes that Hagar wasn't frightened to see angels because she normally saw angels frequenting Avraham's household:

> לְשׁוֹן תֵּמַהּ; וְכִי סְבוּרָה הָיִיתִי שֶׁאַף הֲלוֹם בַּמִּדְבָּרוֹת
>   רָאִיתִי שְׁלוּחוֹ שֶׁל מָקוֹם אַחֲרֵי רֹאִי אוֹתָם בְּבֵיתוֹ שֶׁל
>   אַבְרָהָם שֶׁשָּׁם הָיִיתִי רְגִילָה לִרְאות מַלְאָכִים? וְתֵדַע
>   שֶׁהָיְתָה רְגִילָה לִרְאוֹתָם, שֶׁהֲרֵי מָנוֹחַ רָאָה אֶת הַמַּלְאָךְ
>   פַּעַם אַחַת וְאָמַר מוֹת נָמוּת (שופ' י"ג), וְזוֹ רָאֲתָה ד' זֶה
>   אַחַר זֶה וְלֹא חָרְדָה:
>
> הגם הלום HAVE I ALSO [SEEN] HERE — This is an exclamation of surprise:
>   “could I have ever imagined that here also — in the wilderness — I
>   would see the messengers of the Omnipresent after I have seen them in
>   Abraham’s house, where I saw them regularly!” You may know that she
>   used to see them there regularly from this: That Manoah saw the angel
>   only once and exclaimed, (Judges 13:22) “We shall surely die”, and she
>   saw angels four times, one after the other, and she showed no fear

What were all those angels doing that they were around Avraham's home?

Comment: The angels might have been friends. Even good people are called angels in the Bible. The angels visiting him could also have been a vision or a dream like Rambam.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I don't know, perhaps, visiting him to tell him of the impending destruction of S'dom, to heal him, or perhaps to inform him about the birth of a son, Yitzchak?

In addition, we know that Yaakov Avinu had angels with him (Gen 31:43-32:3) There would be good reason to assume that Avrohom Avinu also had angels with him when he traveled.  We sing on Friday Night "Shalom Aleichem Malachei HaShalom/HaShareis" Avrohom Avinu was able to see and interact with these Malachim, as Yaakov Avinu was in his dream of the ladder (Gen 28:10-22).

There is a principal that Messengers only have an explicit purpose in coming (see Rashi (Gen 18:2).  But that is only lower-level Angels, Michoel, Govriel and Rophael it seems can have multiple purposes and it could be that the angels that frequented his house were none other than these three.

Comment: "visiting him to tell him of the impending destruction of S'dom, to heal him, or perhaps to inform him about the birth of a son, Yitzchak" That all happened many years later.

Comment: "Avrohom Avinu was able to see and interact with these Malachim, as Yaakov Avinu was in his dream of the ladder" How do you know this? Yaakov couldn't interact with them in the dream. Why expect that not only could Avraham interact with them not in a dream, but Hagar saw them too? That's a stretch

Comment: yes it happened many years later....the point being that he was interacting with angels and it was a regular occurrence.  What were they doing there?  Informing him of future events, just like these angels.

Comment: So you are just speculating that the angels mentioned by Rashi were there to predict the future because later some angles did that?

Comment: In the Yaakov ladder episode, we are told that the malachim were going up and down. One is the explanation is that the malachim of Eretz Israel were with the Tzaddik and escorting him. Even if I don't have precise sources, it would make sense it happened also to Avraham Avinu.

Comment: @DoubleAA No, Rashi explicitly says that a.) Avrohom Avinu's home was frequented by Melachim. b.) He says that angels have specific goals. c.) We know that the exception to b.) is Gavriel, Michoel and some say also Rophael. d.) We know that the Avos had Melachim that travelled with them. Putting a-d together suggests that Avrohom Avinu had Melochim, they frequented his home and they had the purpose of telling him information. It would make sense that this information was unique and relevant to Avrohom Avinu. It would seem therefore that the Melachim were there to tell the future.

Comment: "and they had the purpose of telling him information" which part suggests that? It seems like you're just making it up because it's the only known example we have. It seems like you're just generalizing to the extreme.

Comment: So they just came to erm twiddle their thumbs?  If G-d came to you anyway, and you've worked out the point of existence, what on earth do you need angels for?

Comment: I don't know what they came for. That's what this question is asking. There are lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

They were guardians. Even Esav had a guardian angel and so did Yaakov (fun fact: Yaakov fought Esav's guardian and it touched his hip nerve and that’s why we can’t eat that nerve in animals).

Answer (score -2):

"Hagar wasn't frightened to see angels because she normally saw angels frequenting Avraham's household."

Since the Rambam said that angels could be referred to as the natural forces (ie snow, wind, and rain,) it makes sense that she would generally see angles within Abraham's household. Rambam is clear when he says that whenever angels are mentioned in Torah, they are described as a  vision, as angels do not exist in the physical existence. This is the meaning of “He makes His angels winds; His ministers flaming fire” (Psalms 104:4).

See Guide, Book II, chapter XLII.